# Stop links from auto-expanding

Tags: org-mode, org-link

Running Spacemacs 0.300 on Emacs 27.2.

When my cursor is on a link in an org buffer, the link automatically expands. So, what appeared as 'Description' changes to something like [[id:xxxxxx][Description]] the moment my cursor touches 'D'

I do not want this behavior. So, even when I am on 'D', it continues to show 'Description'.

How do I achieve this? Also, in the new set-up, how do I expand the link in case if I want to edit it?

Comment: Are you talking about changes in the buffer or about the "bubble" that gets popped up when you hover over a link?

Comment: @NickD The buffer changes to [[id:xxx][Description]] as my cursor hits the link. As my cursor moves forward, only the 'Desription' is visible.

To make it clear, I am not using mouse.